# SQL: Count rows which are not present in table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I got two tables called: EmployeeTable & TaskAssignmentTable.
They look like this :
[image: tables formation]

TaskAssignmentTable shows tasks assigned to employees. In order to assign new tasks to employees i want to have count of tasks assigned to different people and then assign task to people who have least tasks assigned.
Problem: using normal count() on TaskAssignmentTable results in this table:
[image]

But what i want is some sort of join between tables which shows count of rows which are present in first table and absent in 2nd table with count equal to 0 like this one:

[image]

So what would be the SQL query to join tables and do such thing? (Optional: Since I'm using C# Linq-2-SQL i would be grateful if someone can write LINQ syntax for this).

Comment: Show us something that you have tried?

Comment: i don't know how to use join of tables and count on 2nd table together

Comment: FKemployeeid is an int or a string?? could you provide a sqlfiddle

Comment: What you need is an outer join: read my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375246/sql-count-rows-which-are-not-present-in-table#answer-22375774

Comment: Do you want an SQL answer or a Linq2Sql answer? The translation can be surprisingly "non idiomatic" in Linq2Sql. If a pure SQL answer is sufficient/desired, remove the C#/linq-to-sql tags.

Comment: linq answer would be preferred but not mandotary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` based upon your statement that you want rows that are present in the first table but not the second:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Count(TaskID) as CNT
FROM EmployeeTable e
LEFT JOIN TaskAssignmentTable t 
    ON e.employeeID = t.FKEmployeeID
GROUP BY EmployeeID, Name
```

Comment: Yes I can but can't find the link to your question

Comment: I have now answered your C# question!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Count(TaskID) as CNT
FROM EmployeeTable emp
LEFT JOIN TaskAssignmentTable task on emp.employeeID = task.FKEmployeeID
GROUP BY EmployeeID, Name
```

Comment: i tested your statement but it does not return any rows with count =0. I Mean it still does not present rows absent in 2nd table.

Comment: my snippet was: `SELECT emp.id, Name, Count(taskAssignment.taskID) as CNT
FROM employee emp
JOIN taskAssignment on emp.id = taskAssignment.FKEmployeeID
GROUP BY emp.id, Name`

Comment: Try it with LEFT JOIN. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to use **Left Outer Join**.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Count(TaskID) as CNT
FROM EmployeeTable emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN TaskAssignmentTable task on emp.employeeID = task.FKEmployeeID
GROUP BY EmployeeID, Name
```

And LINQ Version of this query look like this

```
var employees = from emp in dbContext.Employees
                join task in dbContext.TaskAssignmentTable 
                on emp.employeeID equals task.FKEmployeeID
                into tEmpWithTask
                from tEmp in tEmpWithTask.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group tEmp by new { emp.EmployeeID, emp.Name } into grp
                select new {
                  grp.Key.EmployeeID,
                  grp.Key.Name,
                  grp.Count(t=>t.TaskID != null)
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [OUTER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join) the two table (in your case a `LEFT JOIN`):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Count(TaskID) as CNT
FROM EmployeeTable emp
LEFT JOIN TaskAssignmentTable task on emp.employeeID = task.FKEmployeeID
GROUP BY EmployeeID, Name
```